# Disable warning for "unused property" only for specific functions/variables?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

*Original Question:*

I have some JavaScript functions that are only referenced from outside of my project. Is there any way to tell WebStorm not to warn on those but still warn on others? Perhaps with JSDoc or similar syntax?

Example:

```
function externallyCalled() {
    //this should not show a warning if not used
}

function internalFunction() {
   //this should show a warning if it's not used
}
```

Is this possible?

---

*edit:*

Based on Vipin's answer, `// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols` works outside of a closure but not inside:

[image]

I have opened https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-39066 and accepted @Vipin's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols` where you want to suppress the warning like below

```
// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
function externallyCalled() {
    //this should not show a warning if not used
}

// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
function internalFunction() {
    //this should show a warning if it's not used
}
```

**Quick Fix Menu**
[image]

**Edited:**

For closure, one way is to add `// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols` on top of `return` like below

```
var app = (function () {
    // noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
    return {
        externallyCalled: function () {
            //this should not show a warning if not used
        },
        internalFunction: function () {
            //this should show a warning if it's not used
        }
    }
})();
```

This will disable the warnings on all the public properties/methods of returned object.

Comment: Hmm, is there any reason this would not be working? Because it's not.

Comment: Of note, it's not showing up in the quick fix menu (alt+enter)

Comment: I've added quick fix menu snapshot.

Comment: I think I figured it out. These functions are in the `return` of a closure.  I created a test function outside and I was able to supress the check, but inside the closure it does not work.  Ideas?

Comment: Can you post actual part of snippet where it is not working.

Comment: I guess you have done some typo mistake in questions. Can you update it to `var app = (function () {
    return {
        externallyCalled: function () {
            //this should not show a warning if not used
        },
        internalFunction: function () {
            //this should show a warning if it's not used
        }
    }
})();`

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was just a copy/paste mistake. I have updated the code and posted a screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160459/discussion-between-vipin-kumar-and-scott-beeson).